# How do I show $\sup(\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n) \leqslant \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sup(A_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

How do I show that $\sup\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n\right) \leqslant \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sup(A_n)$, where $A_n \subseteq [0,\infty)$? I am looking for a proof of this inequality. Can anyone suggest an idea on how to prove this?

Comment: You can consult a somewhat more general and far-reaching answer below. For the time being, it needs to be mentioned that if one of the terms $A_n$ in your sequence is empty, you would run into some trouble with the series on the right-hand side, as long as you interpret the $\sup$ operator to be the one on the entire extended real line, because in that case $\sup \varnothing=-\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Given a *conditionally complete* ordered set $(A, R)$ -- i.e. an ordered set having the property that any *nonempty* upper-bounded subset $M \subseteq A$ admits a supremum -- one actually has the following:

> *Proposition.* Let $(A, R)$ be conditionally complete and $X \in \left(\mathscr{P}(A)\setminus\{\varnothing\}\right)^I$ be a *nonempty* family of nonempty subsets, which also means that $I \neq \varnothing$. Then the following two statements are equivalent:
> **a)** The union $Y\colon=\displaystyle\bigcup_{i \in I}X_i$ is nonempty and upper bounded and **b)** for each $i \in I$ the subset $X_i$ is nonempty and upper-bounded and furthermore the set of suprema $\left\{\sup X_i\right\}_{i \in I}$ is non-empty and upper-bounded. When these conditions are satisfied one has:

$$\sup\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i \in I}X_i\right)=\sup \left\{\sup X_i\right\}_{i \in I}$$

*Proof.* The argument follows easily from the definition. Assume first that hypothesis **a)** holds. The general hypothesis tells us that $X_i \neq \varnothing$ for every index $i \in I$ and since $X_i \subseteq Y$, whatever upper bound $a \in A$ there exists for the union $Y$ will also be an upper bound for $X_i$. Thus $X_i$ admits a supremum which by definition satisfies $\sup X_i \leqslant_R a$. The set $T\colon=\left\{\sup X_i \right\}_{i \in I}$ of suprema is clearly nonempty since $I \neq \varnothing$ and the previous relation -- that $\sup X_i \leqslant_R a$ for every $i \in I$ -- means nothing else than that $a$ is also an upper bound for $T$.

Conversely, assume now that **b)** holds. Let $b \in A$ be an upper bound for the set $T$ of suprema. Given arbitrary $x \in Y$, there exists $i \in I$ such that $x \in X_i$ and we have by definition that $\sup X_i$ is an upper bound of $X_i$, thus in particular $x \leqslant_R \sup X_i$. Since we also have $\sup X_i \leqslant_R b$, it follows that $x \leqslant_R b$ holds for any $x \in Y$, so that $b$ is established as an upper bound of $Y$ as well. That $Y \neq \varnothing$ is indeed nonempty follows easily from the hypothesis, since $I \neq \varnothing$ allows us to fix a certain index $\alpha \in I$ and claim that $\varnothing \subset X_{\alpha} \subseteq Y$ (where I am referring to *strict* inclusion).

Finally, in order to establish the mentioned relation, let us set $s\colon=\sup \displaystyle\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}X_i\right)$ and $t\colon=\displaystyle\sup_{i \in I} \sup X_i$. It is easy to prove that if $\varnothing \neq S \subseteq T$ and $T$ is upper-bounded, then $\sup S \leqslant_R \sup T$ (the supremum of $T$, being an upper bound for the larger $T$, will also be an upper bound for the subset $S$). This applies in particular to $\varnothing \neq X_i \subseteq Y$, entailing
$\sup X_i \leqslant_R \sup Y=s$, whence by definition of the supremum we furthermore have $t\leqslant_R s$. Conversely, consider an arbitrary $x \in Y$. There exists $i \in I$ such that $x \in X_i$ and therefore $x \leqslant_R \sup X_i \leqslant_R t$. This means that $t$ is in particular an upper bound for $Y$, whence $s \leqslant_R t$, which by antisymmetry of $R$ leads to $s=t$. $\Box$

---

In your concrete case, you seem to be considering a (nonempty) family $X \in \left(\mathscr{P}([0, \infty))\setminus\{\varnothing\}\right)^I$ of nonempty sets of positive real numbers. Since with the standard order the extended positive semi-axis $[0, \infty]$ does indeed form a complete (and thus *conditionally* complete) ordered set, the above proposition applies to the effect that $\sup\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i \in I}X_i\right)=\displaystyle\sup_{i \in I}\sup X_i$. In order to prove the desired inequality, it therefore suffices to show that for any family $x \in [0, \infty]^I$ of extended positive reals the relation:
$$\displaystyle\sup_{i \in I}x_i \leqslant \sum_{i \in I}x_i \tag{*}$$
holds. However, from the elementary **characterisation of summability of arbitrary families of extended positives** we know that:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i \in I}x_i=\displaystyle\sup_{F \in \mathscr{F}(I)} \sum_{i \in F}x_i,$$
where by $\mathscr{F}(M)\colon=\{X \subseteq M|\ |X| \in \mathbb{N}\}$ I am denoting the set of all *finite* subsets of a given set $M$. In other words, the sum of an arbitrary family of extended positive reals exists indeed and is given by the supremum of the family of all finite subsums (i.e. sums of finite subfamilies of the given family). Since in particular the singletons $\{i\} \in \mathscr{F}(I)$ are finite subsets of $I$ for each index $i \in I$, it follows that $\{x_i\}_{i \in I} \subseteq \left\{\displaystyle\sum_{i \in F}x_i\right\}_{F \in \mathscr{F}(I)}$, whence by virtue of the increasing character of the $\sup$ operator we may deduce the desired claim $(^*)$.

**P.S.** To state this last remark it is useful to introduce the notion of *support* of an arbitrary family $y \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}^I$ of extended real numbers by $\mathrm{Supp}(y)=\{i \in I|\ y_i \neq 0\}$. It can be proved without great difficulty that given a nonempty family $u \in [0, \infty]^I$ of extended positives such that $\displaystyle\sup_{i \in I} u_i<\infty$, we have equality $\displaystyle\sup_{i \in I}u_i=\displaystyle\sum_{i \in I}u_i$ in the above general relation $(^*)$ if and only if $|\mathrm{Supp}(u)| \leqslant 1$, in other words if and only if the support of $u$ is at most a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that the inequality might be undefined as any of the following might hold

$$\sup(A_i)=\infty\text{ for some }i=1,2,...$$

$$\sup\left(\bigcup_i^\infty A_i\right)=\infty$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sup(A_i)=\infty$$

$$A_i=\emptyset\text{ for some }i=1,2,...$$

However, assuming that these do not occur (and you can treat these as separate cases if you are willing to say that $\infty=\infty$ and $x\leq \infty$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$) then the inequality is true. [One definition](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/epsilon-definition-of-the-supremum-and-infimum-of-a-bounded) of the supremum states: for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $x\in A$ such that $0\leq \sup(A)-x<\epsilon$. We will use this definition.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Then there exists

$$\alpha\in \bigcup_i^\infty A_i$$

such that

$$0\leq \sup\left(\bigcup_i^\infty A_i\right)-\alpha<\epsilon$$

$$\alpha\leq \sup\left(\bigcup_i^\infty A_i\right)<\alpha+\epsilon$$

Let $k$ be the smallest natural such that $\alpha\in A_k$. This implies

$$\alpha\leq \sup(A_k)$$

$$\sup\left(\bigcup_i^\infty A_i\right)<\alpha+\epsilon\leq \sup(A_k)+\epsilon$$

But then

$$\sup\left(\bigcup_i^\infty A_i\right)< \sup(A_k)+\epsilon\leq \epsilon+\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sup(A_i)$$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude

$$\sup\left(\bigcup_i^\infty A_i\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sup(A_i)$$

Comment: @QC_AQOA The inequality is perfectly defined without absolutely any issues when $\sup A_n=\infty$. The actual problems occur in the case $A_n=\varnothing$. Also -- this is just a remark on proper terminology -- but what you refer to in the text as "one more definition" of the supremum should in all rigour be referred as an equivalent *characterisation* of the supremum in the particular case of ordered additive groups.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I would argue that the supremum is undefined when the set is unbounded, but that is just a matter of definitions. I agree on the empty set portion though (see edit)

Comment: Greetings, for we meet again. I just wanted to say that -- given the current formulation of your answer -- you don't seem to be adopting the position expressed in the previous comment, namely that ''unbounded sets don't have suprema", but rather you seem to be considering the supremum operator defined with respect to the extended ambience $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. In this case, the claim that "the inequality is undefined" only holds in the *unique* instance that one of the terms in the right-hand series is $-\infty$. The case of suprema equal to $\infty$ raises no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

This statement, as written, seems false.

Let $A_1 = \{-5\}$, let $A_2 = \{3\}$ and let $A_i = \{0\}$ for all $i \geq 3$.

Then $sup(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i) = 3 \geq -2 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} sup(A_i)$.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention $A_i \subset X=[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $A_n\neq \emptyset$ for all $n$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, denote $M_{n}=\sup A_{n}\in[0,\infty]$.
Let $x\in\cup_{n}A_{n}$, then $x\in A_{k}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
Therefore, $x\leq M_{k}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_{n}$. This shows
that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_{n}$ is an upper bound of the set $\cup_{n}A_{n}$
and hence $\sup\left(\cup_{n}A_{n}\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sup(A_{n})$.